# Data model in Excel does not filter on foreign key

Tags: excel, foreign-keys, pivot-table, primary-key

I have a simple `Excel` `data model` (see picture), consisting of a *customers* table and an *orders* table. The tables are in separate sheets in the workbook *accounting*. The table *customers* (`primary key`) is linked to the table *order* (`foreign key`) through the column *customer_id*.

But when I create a `pivot table` of the data model, and look e.g. at customer *Becker*, then all the shippers are listed, instead of only the *shippers* Becker uses. This is also the case for all other customers. What did I do wrong?

[image]

*PS: I noticed I made a typo in the column name "customer_id" in the customers table. But that couldn't be the cause of the problem, as the linked columns are not required to have the same names.*

Comment: As the numbers in your customers-table are left aligned: could it be that they are stored as text - compared to the numbers (right aligned) of orders-table?

Comment: Pivot Tables are not intended to be used with nothing in the *Values* field. You need to add some form of aggregation before filtering will take place. Try adding *Count of order_id* to that area, for example.

Comment: @ike Thx. No, they are numbers all right. I did the styling of that column manually.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thx, that worked! Is a bit of hack though. I guess I'd better use MySQL for this problem.